# Book about cube worlds and worms which drill through walls

Tags: story-identification, books

There was a book about cube worlds and some worms which drill through walls. The hero is a slave who cuts wood legs of growing seats. Tables and seats were made from some wood that was growing very fast, so it needed to be cut every evening to adjust for normal height.

The master some fat lady Juvia.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by looking at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), then [edit]ing it to include any further details that come to mind. In particular, it'd be helpful to know in roughly which year you read this, and when you think it might've been published.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome!  I agree that some more information would be helpful, but could you also clarify what you wrote?  What does "wood legs of growing seats" mean?  Thank you.

Comment: And what do you mean by "The master some fat lady Juvia"? Is the hero's master a fat lady? Is she named Juvia?